# View Parametrized Query In VBScript ADODB.Command

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript, ado

How can I view the SQL code of my query *after* it has been parameterized by Parameters.Append

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

Parametrized Queries are not built like a string that you could output when ready.

It's always a two-step process:

1. Prepare a query in the from of "SELECT foo FROM foo_table WHERE id = ?", send it to the server (and get an identifier back).
2. Send all the parameters to fill the question marks to the server, along with the identifier of the prepared statement.

At no point in time the two (query and parameters) get in touch outside of the database server. (This is the reason why parametrized queries are much more secure than hand-made SQL strings).

Comment: Thanks for the info! :-)

ASP can be lame.

Comment: It has nothing to do with ASP. This is the general way things go with parametrized queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can write some simple code to parse the results back out after a fashion by looping through the parameters.  Here is a VBScript / Classic ASP example:

```
        queryPlain = command.CommandText
        For Each p In command.Parameters
           If (p.type = adChar) or (p.type = adBSTR) or (p.type = adDBDate) Then
                queryPlain = Replace(queryPlain , "?", "'" & p.value & "'",1,1)
            Else
                queryPlain = Replace(queryPlain , "?", p.value,1,1)
            End If
        Next
```

Here is something similar for VB.net

```
        queryPlain = command.CommandText
        For Each p As SqlParameter In command.Parameters
            queryPlain = queryPlain.Replace(p.ParameterName, p.Value.ToString())
        Next
```

Now queryPlain contains the SQL including the parameters.  I find this useful for debugging purposes.